# Accessing ArcView 3.X help after Windows 7 install?

Tags: installation, windows-7, documentation, arcview-3

How do I access ArcView 3.X help after Windows 7 install?

ArcView works but I can't access help.

Comment: ArcView 3.3 was placed in Mature support status in [April 2005](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/product%20life%20cycle/other_/ArcViewGIS3xJan2008_PLC.pdf) and Retired in Dec 2012.  Please **edit** your question to specify the application word size for your Windows 7 OS (32-bit or 64-bit).  If the help subsystem is 16-bit and your OS is 64-bit, it's unlikely that they can work together.

Comment: Create single line project startup script System.SetEnvVar ("AVEXT", "C:\......\Esri\AV_GIS30\ARCVIEW\EXT32")

Comment: @Vince It works perfectly fine on Windows 7 with very few tweaks

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArcView_3.x#Windows_7_.26_8_installation_instructions) says that you'll need to download WinHlp32.exe from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

Help files old style are being banned from Win7, 8 and 10.
However, you can try this method, which can make the Help Files live again.

Do not forget to de-activate automatic Windows update.

http://www.trishtech.com/2015/12/how-to-open-hlp-winhelp-files-in-windows-10/